# Tagging Up: edits, synonyms, requests, and other tag-related work

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Because of the nature of sports and the progress of Sports Stack Exchange, our tags are in pretty good shape. However many have issues and we don't often notice what needs to be fixed or know what exactly to do about it.

Answers should include the tag in discussion, and the information or action required. Links to an existing or previous meta question are encouraged. This may be

- an edit the user can't perform directly
- an edit the user is uncertain of how to perform in a suitable way
- synonyms to be proposed
- synonym proposals to be voted on
- requests for a tag to be created
- requests for a tag to be deleted
- requests for a tag to be merged.

Answer (score 6):

### Discussion

The [tag wiki for [swimming]](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/swimming/info)

The tag wiki here feels more appropriate for a Wikipedia page than our tag wikis (which frankly get read very little at all). Would it be sensible to replace it with guidance similar to that which I've just added to the [running tag wiki](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/running/info) which sends recreational questions in the right direction?

Comment: It's also heavily US-centric. Looking at the excerpt now. Leaving the main tag wiki for later.

Comment: Somewhat related post about tag-wikis in general: [What should our tag wiki look like?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/866)

Answer (score 6):

## Discussion

[american-football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-football)

This tag seems to only describe the sport itself, in great detail. Tag wiki should focus on usage rather than a full history and explanation of rules/strategy/players - that's the entire point of questions themselves.

How much of this wiki is reasonable to remove? What else can or should be included in the wiki? Please refer to the tag wiki edit guidance when making further suggestions.

**Proposed construction**

- Remove anything except a basic and brief description of the sport. Link to high-voted, high-viewed questions that expand on the points currently written about.
- Explain the need to include [nfl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfl) or [cfl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfl) or [ncaa](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ncaa) where appropriate, as the same question may have different correct answers for each one.
- Mention [autograph-identification](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autograph-identification) as an important tag when asking to identify autographed American football-related items.

Answer (score 5):

### Complete

[rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules)

[Synonyms for the **rules** tag](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/synonyms)

This tag currently has a proposed synonym [laws](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) with net vote of three (3). It needs one more vote for approval or five more votes for decline.

Comment: Given we have zero questions currently tagged with [tag:laws], I'm not too bothered either way about this one. Do we commonly get new questions tagged with "laws"?

Comment: We had a couple. Someone decided they should be changed to rules instead. Which defeated the purpose of a) using correct terminology and b) creating synonyms.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I searched a bit whether I can find examples of posts that Nij mentioned. Using [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/sports/query/542457/first-10-uses-of-a-tag?tagName=laws) I found [only one post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/2060/revisions) that was tagged ([tag:laws]) in the past. (However, the query does not necessarily finds all questions.)

Comment: It's now approved

Answer (score 3):

## Incomplete

I suggest adding [trophy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophy) and [medal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medal) as a [synonym](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/awards/synonyms)<sup>1</sup> of the tag [awards](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awards). (Or maybe [trophies](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophies) and [medals](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medals), if plurals are preferred in the tag names?)

Both words are commonly used terminology and this would be consistent with the current usage of the tag; there are several questions in this tag including the words [medal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bawards%5D+medal+is:q) or [trophy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bawards%5D+trophy+is:q). 
I have [mentioned this also in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433/2018/1/10) and [Nij recommended to me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42389563#42389563) posting this suggestion here.

<sup>1 Or course, a tag can be suggested as a synonym only if it exists. So,
 technically, this amounts to creating these two tags and then creating (or proposing) the synonym.</sup>

Comment: I've added **medal** to the most recent question about a medal or medals, and proposed the synonym. Needs +4 to approve or -2 to reject.

Comment: Similarly, **trophy** is a proposed synonym. Needs +4 to approve or -2 to reject.

Answer (score 2):

### Discussion

[What is the "participation" tag for?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-is-the-participation-tag-for)

The tag excerpt for [participation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participation) states: "Questions about participation in a sport or event."

This tag doesn't really separate fan questions from player questions nor are they really about how to participate in a sport, as originally intended. However, most of the questions are about prerequisites to participating in events, in which [eligibility](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eligibility) was suggested.

Also, I'm not sure why the following question, [What are the premier Cricket competitions and leagues in the world?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16259/what-are-the-premier-cricket-competitions-and-leagues-in-the-world), is tagged [participation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participation) as the question is about the most desired leagues within a sport rather than the prerequisites of said leagues.

Answer (score 1):

## Complete

The tag [match-fixing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/match-fixing) has been created with a tag wiki and excerpt.

These require approval by review.

See [this proposal with positive consensus](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/a-tag-for-questions-about-match-fixing?/) for more information on the background of this tag's creation.

Answer (score 0):

### Discussion

Do some tags need renamed? The first-page of frequently used tags look good to me.

I came across a meta post of [renaming a tag](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/should-wages-tag-be-renamed) because [one user felt the tag was named incorrectly](https://sports.stackexchange.com/revisions/3299/6). I feel renaming a tag is not necessary if the wiki describes the tag usage unless 1) there is a reasonable discrepancy and 2) there is a consensus on renaming the tag. [wages](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wages) and [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances) are loose synonyms, at worst, and not enough of a reasonable discrepancy. Also, there appeared to be no consensus outside an edit war and a user self-answering in favor of change.

Comment: I can provide a little context for this one.  At some point in the site's past before I arrived on the scene, the tag "wages" was defined as the tag to use for all questions related to the finances of sports.  This caused confusion, because, as we all know, there is more to sports finances than simply the players' contracts.  This caused confusion, which resulted in a minor edit skirmish and the aforementioned meta question.  As a result, the tag we are now using for this is named "finances," which makes much more sense and is less confusing. (continued...)

Comment: "Wages" was made a synonym tag, but remember that "synonym tag" in Stack Exchange does not really mean the same as the word "synonym" in English.  In Stack Exchange, "synonym tags" are simply pointers to the tags that we actually want users to use.  No, the words "wages" and "finances" are not synonyms, but by making "wages" a synonym tag, the system automatically replaces any use of the "wages" tag with the "finances" tag, which is what we want.  If we simply deleted the "wages" tag altogether, someone might create it again in the future, splitting finance questions into multiple tags.(cont.)

Comment: Yes, the [meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460/1723) didn't have much consensus, but it also didn't have any dissent.  There wasn't a lot of meta participation on Sports 5 years ago.  :)  In my opinion, the answer and decision there are still good.

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson, Ben. I can see the cause of confusion, the need for change, and the process to achieve change due to the infancy of the site 5 years ago. I found [an even earlier post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/16112) about tags for American football/football/soccer which had more sustained and prevalent consensus. I guess I brought this up to determine if tags needed renamed and if so, is the means of consensus a discussion (as this post promotes) or a complaint (as the wages/financials tag promotes).

Answer (score 0):

### Discussion

[transfer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) and [transaction](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction)

Transfer's tag excerpt states: "Questions about transfers, or the action taken when a player under contract moves from one club to another."

Transaction's tag excerpt states: "Questions about transactions among organized teams. This may include signings, releases, **trades**, retirements, contract stipulations, and other related actions."

Given trades ≈ transfers, is it appropriate to merge [transfer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) to [transaction](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction)? Or, would it be more appropriate to split [transaction](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction) into a category of tags in which [transfer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) is already a large subset of?

Edit: [draft](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draft) also has a large subset of questions if we were to merge into or split the [transaction](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction) tag.

Answer (score -1):

### Request

[Merge "tactics" and "strategy" tags?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/merge-tactics-and-strategy-tags)

A previous dive into this request showed that users were undecided on merging the tags due to split opinions and lack of usage. With much more usage since, I thought it would be apropos to revisit and make a definitive decision.

Also, as Ben [mentions](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/833/tagging-up-edits-synonyms-requests-and-other-tag-related-work#comment1935_902), "synonym" in Stack Exchange is different than "synonym" in the English language, and "synonym" in English is the reason why this request was made.