# What should our tag wiki look like?

Tags: discussion, tags

While checking a few other things, I ran into the same question I have always been troubled with, but did not feel worth bringing up previously.

Now however, for some semblance of order and consistency, I want to get a consensus (or some approximation of it) on the issue.

> What should a tag wiki include, specifically from the perspective of Sports Stack Exchange, and what should it definitely exclude?

Starting from [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) I think we generally adhere to the standard.

However, for many of our tags, the tag wiki does not look anything like the recommended content. We have such things as a pure listing of the rules of a sport, histories going back centuries, an explanation of playing techniques, and many other things that - while of acceptable but not exemplary writing quality - should really be parts of an encyclopedia or better yet, make up noteworthy portions of a question of an answer elsewhere in the site.

Such a tag wiki also tends to not do what it supposedly should do: explain what the tag is for, how to use, why it exists, the FAQ associated with it, and other functional documentation.

So, what are we going to do about these?

- Remove the background, because it belongs elsewhere and not there?
- Trim the excess down so that people are sure it's the right sport, but are encouraged to ask about everything else they might want to know?
- Some other option that isn't just "keep the *status quo*"?

It will not be helpful or constructive to argue in favour of the *status quo* because we have other work to be done; there are many users who can't or won't or don't apply themselves to existing tasks anyway, and many users who are happy to do multiple jobs. Similarly, naysaying without an explanation that doesn't address the above criticism.