# A tag for questions about match fixing?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [some questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=match+fixing+is:q) about [match fixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_fixing) on this site. How should questions about this topic be tagged?

Some initial thoughts, hopefully other users will add further comments on this.

- Is this topic important enough to create a separate tag [match-fixing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/match-fixing) for it?
- Or should we create a larger tag where match fixing should be one of the subtopics? Perhaps a tag called [cheating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheating)?
- I see that [betting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) is used in some of the current questions. I am not really sure whether all question about match fixing fall under this tag. But if the consensus is that this should be the case, maybe it should be explicitly mentioned [in the tag info](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/betting/info) and also the tag should be added to other questions from the topic.
- Match fixing can have some legal implications. As far as I know, so far there is no tags about legal questions related to sports. (The tag [laws](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) is a [synonym](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/synonyms) of [rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules).) Even if there were such tag, I don't think *all* questions about match fixing would fit under this tag.

Comment: Note that your search for match fixing returns two false positives, due to the spaces between the two words.

Comment: On a tangential note, we do indeed lack a tag for legality, despite a number of questions that would be suitable for it. Bring this up at the [tag work question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/833/tagging-up-edits-synonyms-requests-and-other-tag-related-work) perhaps?

Comment: @Nij Feel free to suggest the new tag (for legal issues) there, or in a separate post. You have much more experience with tags on this site that I do, so it is better if the suggestion (and the assessment to which extent the tag might be useful) comes from you.

Comment: I'd go with **corruption**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update: the tag [match-fixing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/match-fixing) has been created and added to some appropriate questions.

- There are types of cheating which would be of (both academic and practical) interest to all people involved in sports, which do not involve match-fixing.
- One of these types is [doping](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doping), which already exists as a tag on 16 questions. This is perhaps enough to justify a separate existence, and therefore **we should not create an overall [cheating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheating), and we should definitely not create it to contain match-fixing.**
- Betting is also a separate thing from match-fixing. Some fixing does not involve betting, and most betting does not involve fixing, and therefore **we should not include match-fixing under [betting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting)**
- Given the precedent of doping, and the lack of a suitable broader tag, **a tag for match-fixing is appropriate.**